# How to make the TextField expands in flutterwhen the user types in it?

Tags: flutter

I am setting a text field which will expands when Enter is pressed in the keyboard
when i tried to set null in max lines it does not show the text inside text field
i even set that expands = true
i used media query size in somewhere which is size.height in the code
i wrapped the text field within the Flexible widget 
and add some padding then the total flexible widget is wrapped within a Row
and finally the row is wrapped within a Container

so this code is not working help me to fix this

Container(

```
          height: size.height * .059,
          width: double.infinity,
          child: new Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Flexible(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: size.width * 0.007),
                  child: new TextField(
                    controller: _textFieldController,
                    textInputAction: TextInputAction.newline,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                    maxLines: null,
                    expands: true,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                    cursorColor: Colors.blue,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xff8e9291))),
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xff8e9291))),
                      prefixIcon: Icon(
                        Icons.message,
                        color: Color(0xff8e9291),
                      ),
                      hintText: "Type a message",
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xff8e9291),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              FloatingActionButton(
                backgroundColor: Colors.blue[400],
                onPressed: () {
                },
                tooltip: 'Send',
                child: RotationTransition(
                    turns: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(-35 / 360),
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.send,
                      size: 20,
                    )),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

this is the Text field i'm using..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could remove the height of the `Container` since that will make a fixed height, and remove the `expands` of the `TextField` since that is to make it to fill its parent height.

Comment: Thank you very much it is working perfect but i also need to scroll the the text with in the textfield with scrollbar how can i achieve that? is there any possiblities to set listview or Singlechildscrollview within a textfiled???

Comment: TextField already do that. When the TextField has enough text to scroll it will be able to scroll.

Comment: If you want the TextField start scrolling when you have for example 3 lines, you could set the properties minLines: 1 and maxLines: 3

Answer (score 0):

You could set MaxLine property to null 'maxLines: null`
this will enable textField to Expand Vertical